# Need help with a physics question about a ladder leaning against a wall

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, free-body-diagram, equilibrium

I am struggling with a physics question that involves a ladder leaning against a wall. I have attempted to solve the problem, but I am not confident in my answer.

The question is as follows:

"A ladder is leaning against a wall. The angle between the wall and the ladder is $0<\theta<90^{\circ}$. The friction between the ladder and the floor is zero, while the coefficient of friction between the ladder and the wall is $\mu$. Which statement is correct?

A. For equilibrium, $\mu \geq \frac{1}{2} \tan \theta$.

B. For equilibrium, $\mu \geq \tan \theta$.

C. Equilibrium exists regardless of $\theta$.

D. The ladder cannot be in equilibrium and will slide down."

I have tried to visualize the situation and understand the forces acting on the ladder, but I am not sure how to proceed with the calculations. I would appreciate it if someone could help guide me through the steps required to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am not going to do the work for you because you will only learn by doing it yourself. But I will outline the steps. My advice is to try to follow the steps. If you can, then you will have learned. If you cannot, then you will have learned where your lack of understanding lies and from that position you can ask a more focussed question.

Steps are:

1. draw a diagram showing the ladder, floor and wall
2. use your physical intuition to decide what sort of sequence of events might take place
3. add arrows to the diagram, representing the forces acting on the ladder. It is for you to decide what those forces are and where they act, and in what direction.
4. write as much information as you can about each force: can you relate its size to other quantities? Do you know what direction it acts in? etc.
5. for equilibrium we need each force on the ladder to be balanced by an opposite force on the ladder so that there is no net force (including no net torque) and therefore no acceleration. Write down an equation (or more than one equation) asserting that the forces are balanced.
6. use your equation(s) to decide which of the statements is correct

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. 

We could let $L$ be the length of the ladder, and $h$ be the height of the ladder on the wall. The ladder makes an angle $\theta$ with the horizontal, and the coefficient of friction between the ladder and the wall is $\mu$. If the ladder is not in equilibrium, it will slide down the wall due to the force of gravity. The force of friction between the ladder and the wall will oppose the motion of the ladder. We need to consider the forces acting on the ladder: the weight of the ladder acting downwards, the normal force from the wall acting perpendicular to the wall…

Comment: … the frictional force acting opposite to the direction of motion of the ladder, the force of tension from the floor acting parallel to the wall.

Weight of the ladder is given by $mg$, where $m$ is the mass of the ladder and $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity. The normal force from the wall is equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to the vertical component of the tension force from the floor, which is given by $mg \cos \theta$. The frictional force is given by $\mu N$, where $N$ = magnitude of the normal force. The force of tension from the floor is given by $mg \sin \theta$.

Comment: The ladder is in equilibrium, so the sum of the forces in the vertical direction and in the horizontal direction must be equal to zero. Therefore:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \sum F_y=N-m g \cos \theta=0 \\
& \sum F_x=T-f-m g \sin \theta=0
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\$ T \$$ is the magnitude of the tension force, and $\$ \mathrm{f} \$$ is the magnitude of the frictional force. We can solve these equations for $\$ T \$$ and $\$ f:$
$$
\begin{aligned}
& T=m g \sin \theta \\
& f=\mu N=\mu(m g \cos \theta)
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: For equilibrium, we need the force of friction to be greater than or equal to the force of tension. Therefore:
$$
\mu(m g \cos \theta) \geq m g \sin \theta \tan \theta
$$
Simplifying this inequality, we get:
$$
\mu \geq \tan \theta
$$
Therefore, the correct statement is:
B. For equilibrium, $$\mu \geq \tan \theta$$.

Comment: Do we want worked homework problems in the comments? I am glad the answer helped, but the next viewer should also work it out for himself.

Comment: @cricket900 I am puzzled - in the absence of friction with the floor I can't see any physical horizontal force except the normal reaction from the wall. You have found a "tension" on the ladder from the floor which has a horizontal component. Are you assuming the floor is not horizontal?

Comment: 1. comments are not the way to provide answers. 2. fully worked answers to homework are not appropriate for this site. 3 the 'reasoning' in the sequence of comments from cricket900 is confused and wrong